# scroll into view not working on selenium webdriver - Ruby + watir-webdriver using for automation

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, rubygems, watir

We are using ruby + watir-webdriver for our UI automation. recently we have upgraded our firefox from 52ESR to 60ESR. for that we upgraded selenium web-driver from 3.3.0 to 3.4.0 in gem lock file. now browser launching correctly and code is running but below piece of code not working and getting error. Error details given below

```
Ruby Version - ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16) [i386-mingw32]
Selenium web-driver - 3.4.0
watir-scroll - 1.2.0
watir-webdriver - 0.9.0

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
    capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(acceptInsecureCerts: true)
@browser = Watir::Browser.new @browserType, :profile => profile, :desired_capabilities => capabilities
```

i upgraded to 3.4.0 to 3.5.0 and 3.141.0 selenium webdriver gem but no use.

In below code we are getting error:

```
@browser.div(:text=>child_element).wd.location_once_scrolled_into_view

Error:
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
  Element <div id="dojoUnique4" class="dojoDndItem childNode"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

Comment: watir-webdriver is several years old now, please update to using the `watir` gem directly. The code for watir-scroll is also merged into the latest version of Watir. Let us know if you are still seeing an issue after upgrading Watir. Keep up with all of the changes and updates here: http://watir.com/

Comment: Additionally, Firefox v60 is almost a year old.  Not sure why you wouldn't want to test against current version (or even use chrome since it's the dominant browser).

Comment: Given that you have Watir-Scroll, you could try using that for scrolling instead - eg `@browser.div(:text=>child_element).scroll.to :center`

Comment: Hi Titus Fortner, 
i installed watir gem and added in gem lock file.... but not worked. below is my gem lock file.

Comment: Unable to add my gem lock file here